# Trouble with "Last Login" Stored Procedure

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008

Added a column "LastLogin" to a User table, however, it only stores the last login date the first time a user logs in to a password-protected page.

When the same user logs in a second time, the cell does not reflect his last login. Here is my stored procedure:

Here is my stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[UpdateLastLogin] (
@intUserID int
)
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
AS

SET NOCOUNT ON

UPDATE Users SET LastLogin = GETDATE() WHERE UserID = @intUserID
```

Here is my code:

```
public partial class Login : System.Web.UI.Page
{


    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
        //SqlConnection oConnection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["XXXConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        //SqlCommand oCommand = new SqlCommand();
        //oCommand.Connection = oConnection;
        //oCommand.CommandText = "UpdateLastLogin";
        //oCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        //oCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@intUserID", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 10)).Value = Int32.MaxValue;
        //SqlDataAdapter adpt = new SqlDataAdapter(oCommand);
        //DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        //adpt.Fill(ds);
    }
    protected void loginButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["3GPSConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        con.Open();
        string cmdStr = "Select count(*) from Users where UserName='" + userTextBox.Text + "'";
        SqlCommand Checkuser = new SqlCommand(cmdStr, con);
        int temp = Convert.ToInt32(Checkuser.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
        if (temp == 1)
        {
            string cmdStr2 = "Select Password from Users where UserName='" + userTextBox.Text + "'";
            SqlCommand pass = new SqlCommand(cmdStr2, con);
            string password = pass.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
            con.Close();

            if (password == pwdTextBox.Text)
            {
                Session["New"] = userTextBox.Text;
                Response.Redirect("/Protected/Default.aspx");
            }
            else
            {
                userCompareLbl.Visible = true;
                userCompareLbl.Text = "Invalid Password!";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            userCompareLbl.Visible = true;
            userCompareLbl.Text = "Invalid Username!";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Add a "Last Login" column to your User table, and update it when they log in.

Comment: I did add a Last Login column to my User table, however, it only stores the date the first time a user logs in.  The second time, the same user logs in, the cell does not reflect his last login.  I guess I should have phrased my question better.

Comment: Don't you think that would have been relevant information to include in your question?  Your question doesn't reflect your real issue; please edit your question to include the relevant code and update your question title accordingly.

Comment: Please post your ASP code as well; I suspect that you're either passing in an incorret value for `@intUserID` or you're simply not calling `UpdateLastLogin` consistently.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables: I am a newbie to using Visual Studio 2010 so I am still in the learning stage.  Thanks.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables: Will you review my codes and see what I did wrong?

Comment: Your code is riddled with problems.  Your `UpdateLastLogin` code is commented out so that it will never work, and you don't update the login date in your loginButton_Click.  Also, it appears that you are simply storing your passwords as plain text.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables: I know enough to mess my codes up.  My major problem is I can't tell where my problems are.